# Generating Multiple Output files with Hadoop 0.20+

Tags: java, file-io, hadoop

I am trying to output the results of my reducer to multiple files. The data results are all contained in one file, and the rest of the results are split based on a category in their respected files. I know with 0.18 that you can do this with MultipleOutputs and it has not been removed. However, I am trying to make my application 0.20+ compliant. The existing Multiple outputs functionality still requires JobConf (which my application uses Job, and Configuration). How can I generate multiple outputs based on the key?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Support for MultipleOutputs isn't in 0.20. You will need to use the older API.

It has been added into 0.21 which is currently unreleased as org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs.

[This thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-mapreduce-user/200912.mbox/%3C9ec65d4c0912150804o136a36ect41b1d9e6c6fb05b5@mail.gmail.com%3E) on the mailing list talks about this problem.

Comment: That is incredibly frustrating and stupid. That seems like a fundamental thing that is needed in the program.

Comment: Yeah. A lot of work is going on toward having the correct API interface for 1.0

Comment: Not if you use the cdh distrubution. cdh3 which is 0.20.1 plus some patched with MultipleOutputs class. I was initially reluctant to use cdh and was using apache distro. But, after a couple of issues am more happy with cdh.

Answer (score 2):

You can *do* this in Hadoop 0.20, just that as mentioned you have to use the older API.

There's some very rough code to do so in 
  http://github.com/orngejaket/Info_Moist_1_Splicer/tree/master/src/contrib/streaming/src/java/org/infochimps/hadoop/mapred/lib/

The resulting jar writes each record to a file named after its (sanitized) key.