# Using Hadoop to "bucket" data out with a single run

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is it possible to use *one* Hadoop job run to output data to different directories based on keys?

My use case is server access logs.  Say I have them all together, but I want to split them out based on some common URL patterns.

For example,

- Anything that starts with /foo/ should go to /year/month/day/hour/foo/file
- Anything that starts with /bar/ should go to /year/month/day/hour/bar/file
- Anything that doesn't match should go to /year/month/day/hour/other/file

There are two problems here (from my understanding of Map Reduce): first, I'd prefer to just iterate over my data one time, instead of running one "grep" job per URL type I'd like to match.  How would I split up the output, though?  If I key the first with "foo", second with "bar", and rest with "other" then don't they all still go to the same reducers?  How do I tell Hadoop to output them into different files?

The second problem is related (maybe the same?), I need to break output up by the timestamp in the access log line.

I should note that I'm not looking for code to solve this, but rather the proper terminology and high level solution to look into.  If I have to do it with multiple runs, that's alright, but I can't run one "grep" for each possible hour (to make a file for that hour), there must be another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to partition the data just as you describe. Then you need to have multiple output files. See here ([Generating Multiple Output files with Hadoop 0.20+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180101/generating-multiple-output-files-with-hadoop-0-20)).