# Multiple Output in Reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am working on simple map reduce program. I want to create different files after reducer for each different word in the key. For example, after executing Mapreduce I have something like

Priority1 x 2

Priority1 y 2

Priority1 z 2

priority2 x 2

priority2 y 2

Now I want different files after reduce phase, saying Priority1 and Priority2 which have all these values according to the priority. I am using java and want to know what should be written in reducer for having this kind of output?

I just want to know if this is even possible or if it is how to approach or solve this?
I am using Hadoop 0.20.203 and hence multipleoutputs doesn't work.

Any pointers will be helpful. 
Thanks for the help!
Atul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `partioner` class first, that partions based on your criteria.

You then need to create your own `outputformat` class and a `recordwriter` class.

The `recordwriter` class, needs to write to different files as per your needs. Further if you need to sort your values create `comparator` class for your key field.

Comment: Specifically when you create the output format, how exactly do you handle creating a new file for each word? Normally the output files are created when calling OutputFormat.getRecordWriter(context) so how would you know what to name the file?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [MultipleOutputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputs.html).

Comment: I looked at MultipleOutputs but it is not available in hadoop 0.20.203. I apologize I forgot to mention the version of hadoop in my Question. Thanks!! Atul

Comment: ah, okay.  well, i could have asked, too. :) did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180101/generating-multiple-output-files-with-hadoop-0-20?