# Query regarding MultipleOutputs for Hadoop 0.20.203

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to use MultipleOutputs in Reducer so as to write to multiple files using a partitioner. For that, I am trying to construct its object using in Reducer.setup() as follows:

```
public static class MOReduce extends Reducer<Text, Integer, Text, Integer> {
    private MultipleOutputs mos;

    public void setup( Reducer.Context context ) {
        mos = new MultipleOutputs( context.getConfiguration() );
    }
```

But I am facing problem because of following:

- as per the [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html#setup%28org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context%29), setup function takes Reducer.Context as argument
- while as per this [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputs.html#MultipleOutputs%28org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf%29), MultipleOutputs constructor needs JobConf. So, basically I have no way to extract JobConf from Reducer.Context
- I already tried for any function like Reducer.Context.getConfXXX which returns JobConf but there is just one function getConfiguration() which returns JobContext

So, can you please suggest how I can solve this problem and instantiate the MultipleOutputs object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [Multiple Output in Reducer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352905/multiple-output-in-reducer/9368941#9368941)

There are two APIs in hadoop to create and manage mapreduce jobs. One is with `JobConf` and one is with `Job`. You seem to be using one with `Job`. For your case, as in the link above, you need to create your own `RecordWriter` class and `OutputFormat` class. With `RecordWriter` you can control which files to write and when.