# Hadoop MultipleOutputFormats to HFileOutputFormat and TextOutputFormat

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, bulk

I am running an ETL job with Hadoop where I need to output the valid, transformed data to HBase, and an external index for that data into MySQL. My initial thought is that I could use MultipleOutputFormats to export the the transformed data with HFileOutputFormat (key is Text and value is ProtobufWritable), and an index to TextOutputFormat (key is Text and value is Text).

The number of inputs records for an average-sized job (I'll need the ability to run many at once) is about 700 million.

I'm wondering if A) this seems to be a reasonable approach in terms of efficiency and complexity, and B) how to accomplish this with the CDH3 distribution's API, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the old MapReduce API then you can use [MultipleOutputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.203.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputs.html) and write to multiple output formats.

However, if you're using the new MapReduce API, I'm not sure that there is a way to do what you're trying to do. You might have to pay the price of doing another MapReduce job on the same inputs. But I'll have to do more research on it before saying for sure. There might be a way to hack the old + new api's together to allow you to use MultipleOutputs with the new API.

EDIT: Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352905/multiple-output-in-reducer/9368941#9368941). You can probably implement your own [OutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.203.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/OutputFormat) and wrap the appropriate [RecordWriters](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.203.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/RecordWriter) in the [OutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.203.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/OutputFormat) and use that to write to multiple output formats.

Comment: I'm using CDH3u3, which has MultipleOutputs. I'll try that.  Do you think the general approach will be performant?  Any other suggestions?  I'd prefer not to run a second job obviously, since I already have all the data I want in RAM in the reducer.

Comment: I personally haven't used MultipleOutputs but I suspect that it will be pretty efficient. At least more efficient than running a second MR job. My suggestion with this approach is to keep an eye on your spills. While you are gaining performance by not doing a second scan of your data, you're doubling the output of your job, which will likely cause your spills to double. I'd run an experiment with running the job with MultipleOutputs as well as running the job as two separate jobs to see which is more performant.